# How can I use the change of basis theorem to find the standard matrix of a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:\Bbb R^{3}\to\Bbb R^{3}$ be the linear transformation given by reflecting across the plane $x_1 - 2x_2 + 2x_3 = 0$. Use the change of basis formula to find its standard matrix.

What I have tried to do:

I know we have to start with three standard basis vectors in $\Bbb R^{3}$. Then, apply the linear transformation to these standard basis vectors to get the columns of the standard matrix of $T$. But, I’m not sure how does reflecting these vectors across the plane change them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to first find $3$ basis vectors whose reflections will be easy to calculate after applying $T$. The easiest way to achieve this is to choose $2$ linearly independent vectors on the plane of reflection and one that is perpendicular to the plane such that

$$T(v_1)=v_1,\space T(v_2)=v_2 , \space T(v_3)=-v_3$$

After we have chosen our vectors we will be able to write our reflection matrix in terms of our chosen basis thusly:

$$T_B=\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Finding the standard matrix for $T$ is now a simple matter of applying the change of basis formula $S\circ T_B\circ S^{-1}$ where we have

$$S=\begin{bmatrix}
    v_1 & v_2 & v_3 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

So, in total, we will have

$$\therefore T_S=\begin{bmatrix}
    v_1 & v_2 & v_3 \\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    v_1 & v_2 & v_3 \\
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}$$

I'll leave the choice of basis and specific calculations to you...